# Coefficient of static and kinetic friction of brass over aluminium, brass over wood and brass over perspex plastic

Tags: forces, friction, resource-recommendations, material-science, data

Hi can someone please help with a reference to the following constants static and kinetic friction of brass over aluminium, brass  over wood and brass over perspex plastic.

I am just looking for a reference that gives the constant friction values.

I am not able to find it,

Comment: It is a good question. Data tables for such physical properties of materials ought to be available on this site IMO. Unfortunately there are many common materials and many more combinations. Online tables tend to repeat the same combinations. Your combinations are not popular enough.

Comment: Is there really no similar solution to this?

Comment: No similar solution to what? The coefficients you need probably exist somewhere in materials science literature, but it is not easily found by internet search, and might be off-line. If you have access to these materials, it might be easiest to make a measurement yourself.